# I want to add more time to this relay delay

Tags: relay, timer

The maximum is 3 seconds, I want it to be 5 minutes or even 10 minutes if possible.

What should I do in terms of changing capacitors or resistors etc?

Thamk you.

I tried to reverse engineer it,This is what I got:

[Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ad%20544%20-64%20512%20-96%202%20default%0Ad%20544%20-64%20512%20-32%202%20default%0Ad%20512%20-96%20480%20-64%202%20default%0Ad%20512%20-32%20480%20-64%202%20default%0Ar%20368%20-96%20304%20-96%200%20100000%0Ar%20368%20-32%20304%20-32%200%20150%0Ar%20240%20160%20240%20256%200%2056000%0Ar%20288%20192%20288%20288%200%20150%0Ar%20352%20176%20352%20224%200%202100%0Ar%20400%20208%20400%20272%200%20560%0Ar%20464%20176%20528%20176%200%2047%0Ar%20464%20208%20528%20208%200%201000%0Ar%20528%20448%20448%20448%200%202700%0A209%20128%20112%20128%20160%200%200.000022%200.001%201%0A209%20400%20160%20448%20160%200%200.000047%200.001%201%0Ad%20528%20112%20400%20112%202%20default%0A162%20560%20352%20528%20352%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A178%20528%2032%20448%2032%200%201%200.2%200%200.05%201000000%200.02%2020%0Ac%20560%20176%20560%20208%200%201e-8%200.001%0Ad%20512%20320%20464%20320%202%20default%0Ad%20560%20400%20464%20400%202%20default%0At%20304%20144%20256%20144%200%201%200%200%20100%0Ad%20352%20448%20448%20448%202%20default%0Aw%20544%20-64%20560%20-64%200%0Aw%20560%20-64%20560%20144%200%0A177%20496%20240%20560%20240%201%200%200%200.01%200.0082%2050%0Aw%20480%20-64%20448%20-64%200%0Aw%20448%20-64%20448%20-32%200%0Aw%20448%20-32%20368%20-32%200%0Aw%20304%20-32%20304%200%200%0Aw%20304%200%20544%200%200%0Aw%20544%200%20544%2064%200%0Aw%20544%2064%20528%2064%200%0Aw%20528%2080%20528%20112%200%0Aw%20560%20400%20560%20352%200%0Aw%20528%20352%20528%20448%200%0Aw%20464%20400%20368%20400%200%0Aw%20352%20400%20352%20448%200%0Aw%20368%20400%20352%20400%200%0Aw%20560%20208%20528%20208%200%0Aw%20528%20176%20560%20176%200%0Aw%20560%20240%20576%20240%200%0Aw%20576%20240%20576%20448%200%0Aw%20576%20448%20528%20448%200%0Aw%20448%20160%20448%20144%200%0Aw%20560%20144%20560%20176%200%0Aw%20448%20144%20560%20144%200%0Aw%20544%2064%20544%20128%200%0Aw%20544%20128%20400%20128%200%0Aw%20400%20128%20400%20160%200%0Aw%20400%20112%20400%20128%200%0A174%20368%20352%20432%20320%201%20100000%200.5%20Resistance%0A174%20240%20320%20272%20256%201%202000%200.5%20Resistance%0Aw%20528%20352%20528%20320%200%0Aw%20528%20320%20512%20320%200%0Aw%20464%20320%20464%20240%200%0Aw%20464%20240%20496%20240%200%0Aw%20464%20240%20448%20240%200%0Aw%20448%20240%20448%20176%200%0Aw%20448%20176%20528%20112%200%0Aw%20400%20272%20400%20320%200%0Aw%20400%20160%20400%20208%200%0Aw%20272%20288%20288%20288%200%0Aw%20128%20160%20208%20160%200%0Aw%20208%20160%20240%20160%200%0Ax%20246%20113%20289%20116%204%2024%20UJT%0Ax%20497%20278%20547%20281%204%2024%20SCR%0Aw%20128%20160%20128%20448%200%0Aw%20352%20448%20128%20448%200%0Aw%20576%20240%20624%20240%200%0Aw%20624%20240%20624%20176%200%0Aw%20624%20176%20560%20176%200%0Aw%20352%20224%20352%20352%200%0Aw%20352%20352%20384%20352%200%0Aw%20384%20352%20368%20352%200%0Aw%20352%20176%20352%20128%200%0Aw%20352%20128%20352%2080%200%0Aw%20352%2080%20128%2080%200%0Aw%20128%2080%20128%20112%200%0Aw%20448%20448%20448%20352%200%0Aw%20432%20352%20448%20352%200%0Aw%20240%20320%20240%20368%200%0Aw%20240%20368%20432%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20368%20432%20352%200%0Aw%20256%20160%20256%20192%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20288%20192%200%0Aw%20352%20128%20304%20144%200%0Aw%20256%20128%20256%2048%200%0Aw%20256%2048%20384%2048%200%0Aw%20384%2048%20384%20192%200%0Aw%20384%20192%20464%20192%200%0Aw%20464%20208%20464%20192%200%0Aw%20464%20176%20464%20208%200%0Av%20736%20-128%20736%20-32%200%201%2050%2024%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20736%20-128%20512%20-128%200%0Aw%20512%20-128%20512%20-96%200%0Aw%20512%20-32%20736%20-32%200%0A)

[image]
[image]

Comment: it doesn't seem practical to increase the time by that amount by swapping parts.

Comment: @Jasen, Is it impossible? I learned that by changing some resistors and capacitors you can increase time.

Comment: you want to make it 100 times longer. it's not not impossible, but you will nee low leakage capacitors  which means polyester which means they will be much bigger than the ones you have.  I would be looking to use a digital timer module instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Jasen said, and as common sense kind of suggests: once you're changing the way a device works by multiple orders of magnitude, you typically have to redesign the device, rather than just change a couple components.

So, no, you cannot just exchange a couple of things. You need to exchange basically everything.

An analog timer circuit with 10 minutes hold is hard to build reliably, because you need very large capacitors, which means they are very inaccurate.

Considering the large size of this PCB and its components, you should be able to design a PCB that carries the same or a similar relay, and a microcontroller. Since you really don't need much from that microcontroller, that would put you in the 50ct region of component cost. So, full PCB + microcontroller + relay + passives would be < 5€. That's a no-brainer. Design your own PCB, or use a timed relay that integrates that functionality from the start.